# Creating Thumbnail from Video - Improving Speed Performance via MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

This is my code by which is i am using. I want to generate thumbnail after that i create a video via these thumbnail with drawing which is done on "drawImage" UIImageView.

```
   while([self.thunbnailArray count])
    {
        id times = [self.thunbnailArray objectAtIndex:0];////self.thumbnailArray contains duratin of player at which thumbnail generate//////
        [self.thunbnailArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        UIImage* thumbnail = [player1 thumbnailImageAtTime:[times floatValue]             timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionExact];

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(drawImage.frame.size);////drawImage is a UIImageView to make drawing
        [drawImage.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
        UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        CGImageRef firstImageRef = thumbnail.CGImage;/////merge thumbnail and drawing both together
        CGFloat firstWidth = CGImageGetWidth(firstImageRef);
        CGFloat firstHeight = CGImageGetHeight(firstImageRef);
        CGSize mergedSize = CGSizeMake(firstWidth, firstHeight);
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(mergedSize);
        [thumbnail drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, firstWidth, firstHeight)];
        [viewImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, firstWidth, firstHeight)];
        UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        [self.imageArray addObject:newImage];///self.imageArray used to generate video

    }
```

Comment: You want to generate thumbnails?  Go right ahead.

Comment: yes i want to generate thumbnails.

Comment: @TBlue i want generate thumbnail but this code is not perform well app is crashed due to loop is called a thousands of time....